# Improving Baumgartner's result?

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, analytic-functions

Q1: Is it consistent with the failure of CH to have an $\aleph_1$-dense subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of size $\aleph_1$, there is a $C^{\infty}$ map $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ sending $X$ into $A$?

Q2: Is it consistent with the failure of CH to have an $\aleph_1$-dense subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ such that for every $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ of size $\aleph_1$, there is an analytic function $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ sending $X$ into $A$?

What I know: If we replace $C^{\infty}$ by continuous, a positive answer to Q1 follows from PFA. If we replace analytic by continuous in Q2, a positive answer follows from MA.

Thanks!

Comment: The paper "[Homeomorphisms with Small Twist](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5813.pdf)" by Kunen gives some generalizations of the results you mentioned at the end of your question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your first question is no. Proposition 9.4 in Abraham, Rubin and Shelah ["On the consistency of some partition theorems..."](http://www.winterschool.eu/files/on_the_consistency_of_some_partition_theorems.pdf) implies that there are $\aleph_1$-dense sets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that there is no $C^1$ function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f[A] \subseteq B$. See also Proposition 1.2 in M. Burke, ["Entire functions mapping uncountable dense sets of reals onto each other monotonically"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2009-361-06/S0002-9947-09-04924-1/). On the other hand, if you only consider $A$ and $B$ which are everywhere of second category, you get a positive answer. This is Theorem 2.1 in the second paper.

Comment: Q1 seems to have a yes answer by Theorem 2.1 of Burke's paper.

Comment: That talks about a restricted form of Q1 (which I mention in the second-last sentence).

Comment: In the model of Theorem 2.1, can't you take $A$ to be an everywhere non meager set of size $\aleph_1$?